# Oracle EBS Log File : how to redirect output java to ebs log file?

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

How to redirect output java to ebs log file??

I have a program named `TU_AP_AR_SIS` written in java, and I want to see the output into the ebs log file.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: thank you vey much for example i have this out put en java                           System.out.println("xml extension valide");                                                        how i can redirect this out put to the log file ebs??